# How to write a function to return a random element from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
function randomElement(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}
```

got this far but i feel like i am missing something....I'm using const not var and using javascript!

help!

cheers!

Comment: So... what is your question?

Answer (score -1):

I'm such an idiot, as soon as I posted my question I worked it out.....

The code is:

```
function randomElement(array) {
  const findRandom = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
  return findRandom;
}
```

Comment: But why not just returning it as in your question?

Comment: why do you think that this code does anything different than the other one?